# How to study uniform convergence of $\arctan\left(e^{\frac x n}\right)$, $x>0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Study the uniform convergence of the functional sequence $f_n$ on the given set.
> a) $f_n(x)=\cos\frac{\pi x^n}2$, $x\in[0,0.99]$;
> b) $f_n(x)=\arctan\left(e^{\frac x n}\right)$, $x>0$.

Hi. My problem is with (b).

I am getting that $f_n(x)\to\frac\pi 4$.

Need to find epsilon such that $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\le\epsilon$.

So $\arctan\left(e^{\frac x n}\right)-\frac \pi 4 \le \epsilon$.

Am stuck here. What I did until this step is right? How to continue from this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not  uniformly convergent for $x>0$. Note that $\arctan (e^{x/n})=\arctan e$ when $x=n$. So uniform convergence would imply that $|\arctan(e)-\frac {\pi} 4|$ is less than $\epsilon$. But this fails if $0<\epsilon <|\arctan(e)-\frac {\pi} 4|$.

Comment: Thanks for response.The moment at  arctan(x/n) I didn't understand.How you get it?

Comment: @HrantBaloyan Sorry, there was a typo.